# Marionette view not closing after navigating away

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model-view-controller, marionette

We have several types of tags, but they belong to the same data set.  Our collections are set similarly to this though

```
api/tags.json?category=state
```

Our marionette structure looks like this:

```
  1:Select Tag Category (LayoutView)
   2:[Category:State,Type,Product,Company] Tags List (CompositeView)
    3:Add / Edit [Category] Tag (ItemView)
```

Problem is, if we are in the third or second level on one category, select the first level, and navigate to a different category of tags, the previous collection persists.  This is true if you continue into the add/modify, it also persists with the old model.

If anything is confusing let me know, but I think that explains my problem.  Any pointers / advice would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Added Controller / Router

```
        DocRepoTags:function(category) {
            this.reloadHeader({'title': 'Document Repository', 'subnav': subnav(docRepoMenu)});
            App.mainRegion.destroy();
            App.mainRegion.show(new DocRepoTagsView({category:category}));
        },
        DocRepoTagsCategory:function() {
            this.reloadHeader({'title': 'Document Repository', 'subnav': subnav(docRepoMenu)});
            App.mainRegion.destroy();
            App.mainRegion.show(new DocRepoTagsCategoryView());
        },
        DocRepoTagsAdd:function(category) {
            this.reloadHeader({'title': 'Document Repository', 'subnav': subnav(docRepoMenu)});
            App.mainRegion.destroy();
            App.mainRegion.show(new DocRepoModifyTagsView({category:category}));
        },
        DocRepoTagsEdit:function(category, key) {
            this.reloadHeader({'title': 'Document Repository', 'subnav': subnav(docRepoMenu)});
            App.mainRegion.destroy();
            App.mainRegion.show(new DocRepoModifyTagsView({category:category, key:key}));
        }
```

And then here are the routes:

```
'doc-repo/tags': 'DocRepoTagsCategory',
'doc-repo/tags/:category': 'DocRepoTags',
'doc-repo/tags/:category/add': 'DocRepoTagsAdd',
'doc-repo/tags/:category/edit/:id': 'DocRepoTagsEdit'
```

Comment: How can an ItemView (level 1) be a parent to a CompositeView (level 2)? Is Level 1 supposed to be a LayoutView? And also, to be able to help you may want to show how your routing code (i.e. your router and controller) fundamentally works.

Comment: Changed it to a layoutview, added additional code.  Issue persists.